# how to find correlation coefficient when X and Y follows Poisson Distribution?

Tags: probability, self-study, correlation, poisson-distribution, joint-distribution

A bridge is examined for corrosion. It is believed that the corrosion on left side exist is poisson distributed with mean 3 and corrosion on right side is poisson distributed with mean 1.5+0.5X where X is the number of corrosion left side. As more corrions on left side believed to suggest more on right side.
If X and Y are the places wiyh corrosion on left and right side respectively.What is the coefficient of correlation ρ of X and Y? 
I tried don't know weither i got right or wrong
[image: TRIED]

can anyone help how to compute?

Comment: Your solution seems to have an undefined $Z$ and to be incomplete. Clue as to answer. Simulation in R: `set.seed(1114); x = rpois(10^6, 3); y = rpois(10^6, 1.5+.5*x); cor(x,y)` returns 0.4473135. Should be accurate to about 2 places. // Why is $Var(Y) > Var(X)?$

Comment: @BruceET this is what i concluded from the question that V(Z) =1.5+0.5(X) am l right or wrong?

Comment: @BruceET how to compute E(XY) with given info.

Comment: This question is a bit odd. Y seems to result from compounding a Poisson distribution with the mean/rate distributed according to another Poisson distribution. So it is not really "X and Y follows a Poisson distribution". Anyway the answer given by a_statistician works. You do not have to integrate to get the compound distribution, just integrate to get the variance and mean.

Answer (score 2):

1. Replace Z by Y in your equation.
2. $Var(Y)=E_X(Var_Y(Y|X)) + [Var_X(E_Y(Y|X))]^2%$
3. $E(XY)=E_X(E_Y(XY|X)) = E_X(XE(Y|X)) = E_X(X(1.5+0.5X))$ 
   $= E_X(1.5X + 0.5X^2)) =1.5*3 + 0.5E(X^2) = 4.5 +0.5E(X^2)$
4. $E(Y)= E_X(E_Y(Y|X))$

Comment: How to compute E(XY) can you tell me numericaly

Comment: Get the conditional mean (conditional on X), i.e, consider X as constant, get the mean of Y. It will contain X. The get the mean over X.

Comment: Would you like to solve how to compute plz. This problem just turn my head

Comment: See I added in Answer. For $E(X^2)$, use the relation between it, variance and mean.

Comment: Getting closer; put it together: $Var(X) = E(X^2) - \mu_X^2,$ so $E(X^2) = 12, E(XY) = 10.5.$ Then $E(XY) = Cov(X,Y) + \mu_X\mu_Y = 10.5+9,$ so $Cov(X,Y) = 1.5.$ Then find $\rho=Cor(X,Y),$ for which you still need $Var(Y) = 3.75 > Var(X) = 3.$